# Libreoffice Writer: format headings like the web's "inline-block" behaviour

Tags: libreoffice

(Ubuntu 20.04, Libreoffice version 6.4.7.2) (An answer for a newer version is also welcome.)

---

I would like to format a series of headings in a document (all are h2 level).

For the sake of efficiency, I would like to use the "Styles" feature, wherein I can edit the visual rules for all headings in a single place, and where administered changes will update all instances of headings at once.

(The "Styles" sidebar can be opened with the F11 shortcut key. The corresponding dialog windows are also accessible through right clicking any heading, then from the appearing context menu, hovering "Paragraph", then from the flyout menu, chosing "Edit styles".)

I wish to use a background color and a border for the headings; normally, these features will show up in the full width of the page, from left page margin to right page margin, even if the heading's text constitutes only a single word. (This is comparable to the web's "block" layout behaviour.)

I however wish that my background-colors and borders apply only immediately around the text nodes, in a "stretch" fashion. (This is comparable to the web's "inline", or "inline-block" behaviour.)

I have found two (unsatisfactory) workarounds:

- one can update the *right* indent of each heading manually, and adjust its width to match the text nodes inside
- one can select the text nodes, and apply "Character"-level formatting to them, where a proper background feature is not, but at least the border feature is available.

Both of these workarounds have the following drawbacks:

- they need to be carried out manually for each instance, which is not desirable,
- both of these methods inadvertently "freeze" / override some styling features, and thus, such formatted texts will not be receptive to subsequent modifications through the collective "Styles" feature.

Is there a trick that would enable what I am after, but solely through the "Styles" feature?

Comment: Not sure why this LibreOffice question is getting asked here. Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice)  would likely generate better solutions.

Comment: or [ask libre office](https://ask.libreoffice.org/tags/c/english/5/calc)